# How to configure the google api api_key on Android

Tags: android

Using an example, I found the `android:name` attribute for the maps api

```
<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
    android:value="your_api_key"/>
```

Now I am trying to use the calandar api, and I have been unsuccessful so far.. I am unsure as to the `android:name` value I should be using here.

```
<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.calendar.v3.API_KEY"<!-- the value ?-->
    android:value="your_api_key"/>
```

The response:

```
"code": 403,
"errors": [
{
"domain": "usageLimits",
"message": "Access Not Configured",
"reason": "accessNotConfigured"
}
],
"message": "Access Not Configured"
}
```

Anyone know what else I need to do to configure this properly?

call google api:CalendarList feed = client.calendarList().list().setFields(CalendarInfo.FEED_FIELDS).execute();

```
//Traffic Reports for API Project
Total requests
2
Requests/day
2 peak 0.07 average
Start Date
Jun 12, 2013
```

**resolve it:**

The Manifest.xml

```
<application ... >

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.calendar.v3.API_KEY"
        android:value="your api key"/>
....
</application>
```

**Google API Access:https://code.google.com/apis/console**
 1. if you debug,need add a application,Client ID for installed
    applications： **Certificate fingerprint (SHA1)**:「keytool -list -v
    -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore  Input the password:android」
 2. Application type:   Android
 3. find API KEY:**Simple API Access**-->Key for browser apps (with
    referers)-->API key: dhjkl..hjkl
 4. find Product name:  **Branding information**-->Product name

Then call the API:

```
final HttpTransport transport = AndroidHttp.newCompatibleTransport();

final JsonFactory jsonFactory = new GsonFactory();

GoogleAccountCredential credential;

credential =
GoogleAccountCredential.usingOAuth2(getActivity(),
        Collections.singleton(CalendarScopes.CALENDAR_READONLY));
credential.setSelectedAccountName("myAccount");
client = new com.google.api.services.calendar.Calendar.Builder(
        transport, jsonFactory, credential).setApplicationName("myAppName")
        .build();
...
checkGooglePlayStatus() 
... 
...
//doInBackground()
CalendarList feed = client.calendarList().list().setFields(CalendarInfo.FEED_FIELDS).execute();
...
```

Comment: How did you add the `<meta-data>` in your `manifest.xml` ? Can youpost it please.

Comment: which calendar api you are trying to access?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to provide anything in manifest that's just for Google Maps for Android.

If you are trying to use Calendar API v3 (https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/) then first you need to authenticate using OAuth 2.

Here's an example on Google website of how to use Calendar API v3 on Android https://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/wiki/OAuth2#Android

Comment: Thank you
the reason:setApplicationName("myAppName") it must your  ApplicationName
    credential =
    GoogleAccountCredential.usingOAuth2(getActivity(),
            Collections.singleton(CalendarScopes.CALENDAR_READONLY));
    SharedPreferences settings = getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    credential.setSelectedAccountName("myAccount");
    client = new com.google.api.services.calendar.Calendar.Builder(
            transport, jsonFactory, credential).setApplicationName("myAppName")
            .build();